# Two django ORM query that should do same thing are doing different thing

Tags: django, django-orm

take a look at these 2 function following:

```
def get_recommended_products_IT_WORKS(request):
    carrello = get_basket(request)
    articoli_carrello = Articolo.objects.filter(
        variantearticolo__rigareferenza__referenza__paginavendita_referenza__rigacarrello__carrello=carrello)

    TEMP = Referenza.objects.filter(rigareferenza__variante_articolo__articolo__in=articoli_carrello)
    recommended_products = RecommendedProduct.objects.exclude(paginavendita_referenza__referenza__in=TEMP)

    return recommended_products


def get_recommended_products_IT_DOESNT_WORK(request):
    carrello = get_basket(request)
    articoli_carrello = Articolo.objects.filter(
        variantearticolo__rigareferenza__referenza__paginavendita_referenza__rigacarrello__carrello=carrello)

    recommended_products = RecommendedProduct.objects.exclude(
        paginavendita_referenza__referenza__rigareferenza__variante_articolo__articolo__in=articoli_carrello)

    return recommended_products
```

To me, it seems that they should return the same results, but it's not working this way.
The former works like I need and the latter not.
Can you give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean ``articoli_carello`` queryset? Can you show the results of  both queries, and ``carello`` variable?

Comment: No, I mean what I get in recommended_products in the two different case

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What's being returned from each of the methods?